# Is there a $\lambda \in [0,1]$ so that $-\delta \leq \lambda a +(1-\lambda )b\leq \delta$?

Tags: real-numbers

Let  $a<\delta$ and $-\delta <b$ for some $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\delta >0$. Is there a $\lambda \in [0,1]$ so that  $-\delta \leq \lambda a +(1-\lambda )b\leq \delta$?

Comment: @Surb How do you conclude that $[a,b] \subset (-\lambda,\lambda)$?

Comment: @Surb Generally, $a$ is not less than $b$.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $b\le a$ then $-\delta < b \le a < \delta$, so $\lambda=0$ will do. If $b>a$ then $c=\max(a,-\delta) \in [a,b] \cap [-\delta,\delta]$ and can be written as a convex combination of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.